# SEAM JSF Lazy Init Exception on bean property

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam, seam-conversation

I am experiencing an issue with Lazy initialization exception in my SEAM (2.2.2) Application, I am using a SEAM managed persistance context (with JPA), described in the documentation here

SEAM Docs Ref. [9.3.1 SEAM Managed Persistance Context with JPA](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/persistence.html#d0e7372)

Whereby the entity manager is injected using @In in my GenericDAO class

**Scenario:**

I have a conversation scoped bean which injects the currently logged in user entity (session scoped), the LIE seems to be thrown when I attempt to lazily load some additional user attributes via JSF (el) in the page.

**Stack trace error:**

```
2012-12-24 15:30:34,661 SEVERE [facelets.viewhandler] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) Error Rendering View[/user/settings.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /user/settings.xhtml: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

at com.webapp.entities.Client_$$_javassist_29.getLogoUrl
```

At first I thought maybe the conversation had timed out, but this is handled by logging the user out, not throwing a LIE

So now I thought that maybe because the user entity is being injected from the session scope and the action bean is conversation scoped the object is somehow detached from the entity manager?

Unfortunately the exception is not thrown every time, so I cannot easily reproduce it (the application is live so I am getting the errors through as and when)

I know I can solve this by setting the user properties to load EAGERLY but I want to get to the bottom of this first and would prefer not to load all entities up front

**More details on my setup:**

components.xml:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
    auto-create="true"
    persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/EntityManagerFactories/appData">  
</persistence:managed-persistence-context>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="AppDatabase">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/appDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/appDatasource"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/EntityManagerFactories/appData"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/> 
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

GenericDAO

```
public abstract class GenericDAOBean<T>
    implements GenericDAO<T>, Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Class<T> entityBeanType;

@In private EntityManager em;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericDAOBean() {
    this.entityBeanType = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

/**
 * Set the entity manager to use
 * 
 * @param em
 */
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

/**
 * Get the current seam entity manager
 * 
 * @return
 */
 protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
 //Seam entity manager set this way as of version 2.2.0 
 //can't handle abstract classes and @In doesn't inject
 //into this as a parent class
 EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager)Component.getInstance("entityManager");
 if (entityManager == null)
     throw new IllegalStateException("Seam EntityManager has not been set on "
     +getEntityBeanType().getClass().getName()+"DAO before usage!");
     return entityManager;
 }

//Further Generic method follow here which are removed for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you getting your User entity from action bean try in your action bean

User user=entityManger.find(User.class,User.getId());

this should load it into extended persistance context since it looks like it is detached

**Edit** after your comment.

You certainly dont  do it in your getter method, just do it once in any method preceding your acces to the bean and it will be atached to your extended PC, I'd say do it in @Create method of your action bean. About your last question: has it ever been loaded into Seam-managed persistence contexts which is conversation bound?

Also you should inject your entity manager with '@In EntityManager entityManager' since this is your configuration of a managed persistence context in your application.xml. And if your entity has ever been loaded into EPC within this conversation just that should be enough.

Comment: But as I am accessing the User entity via JSF (el), I would have to add the .find() method to the Getter, which means I would be re-loading the entity every time its referenced in the page! I would prefer to find out why the entity is getting detached in the first place

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will try adding to the @Create method as you suggest, I am already using '@In EntityManager em' in my GenericDAO abstract class (see original post), or are you suggesting it needs to be injected into the action bean as well?

Comment: your configuratin is   'name="entityManager"' or name="em"? be consistent, Entity manager can be injected where you need it. I am suggesting that In '@Create' marked method, that is called only once, you introduce your User not entityManager to your extended persistance context for this conversation. And you can do it by 'user=entityManger.find(User.class,user.getId()) . It is the lazy loading problem of an object that is not attched to your extended persistence context of running conversation and that object is user.

Comment: @DaveB have you tried using @Factory?  If you use that annotation it won't be reloaded unless it's null.